# Segfault with ulimit -s unlimited

Tags: c, linux, unix

On linux, I have a program that crashes only if ulimit -s is set to unlimited.
The place where it segfaults is in a connection callback in Libmicrohttpd, so the backtrace is pretty deep (around 10 functions tacked up).
Whatever the function I call first in this callback is where it crashes, even if it is just printf. Here is a stacktrace from coredump :

```
#0  0x000000341fa44089 in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000341fa4ef58 in fprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x000000000044488d in answer_to_connection (cls=0x7fffc57b0170, connection=0x2b59bc0008c0, url=0x2b59bc000a84 "/remote.html",     method=0x2b59bc000a80 "GET", version=0x2b59bc000a9f "HTTP/1.0", upload_data=0x0, upload_data_size=0x2b59b94247b8, con_cls=0x2b59bc000918) at network.c:149
#3  0x00000000004f7f9f in call_connection_handler (connection=connection@entry=0x2b59bc0008c0) at../../../src/microhttpd/connection.c:2284
#4  0x00000000004f92f8 in MHD_connection_handle_idle (connection=connection@entry=0x2b59bc0008c0) at ../../../src/microhttpd/connection.c:3361
#5  0x00000000004fae81 in call_handlers (con=con@entry=0x2b59bc0008c0, read_ready=<optimized out>, write_ready=<optimized out>, force_close=<optimized out>) at ../../../src/microhttpd/daemon.c:1113
#6  0x00000000004fd93b in thread_main_handle_connection (data=0x2b59bc0008c0) at ../../../src/microhttpd/daemon.c:1965
#7  0x0000003420607aa1 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#8  0x000000341fae8bcd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

If I set ulimit -s to, say 8192, everything works.
I am used to bugs where one has to increase stack size.
But why would it work with a smaller stack, and fail with unlimited ?

**EDIT :**

It definitively has to do with threads. Simple example :

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char arg){
  char buffer[666666];

  if(arg > 0){
    memset(buffer, arg, 6666);
    fprintf(stderr, "DONE %p\n", &buffer);
    function(arg - 1);
  }
}

void *thread(void *arg){
  int a;

  fprintf(stderr, "THREAD %p\n", &a);

  function(6);

  return NULL;
}

int main(){
  int i;
  pthread_t p;

  fprintf(stderr, "MAIN %p\n", &i);

  pthread_create(&p, NULL, thread, NULL);

  pthread_join(p, NULL);
}
```

With ulimit -s 8192 :

```
$ ./test 
MAIN 0x7ffd73f9cc5c
THREAD 0x7fa4d12bfeac
DONE 0x7fa4d121d250
DONE 0x7fa4d117a600
DONE 0x7fa4d10d79b0
DONE 0x7fa4d1034d60
DONE 0x7fa4d0f92110
DONE 0x7fa4d0eef4c0
```

With ulimit -s unlimited

```
$ ./test 
MAIN 0x7ffd1438d4dc
THREAD 0x2ab91aef6eac
DONE 0x2ab91ae54250
DONE 0x2ab91adb1600
DONE 0x2ab91ad0e9b0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: It doesn't - you're probably using undefined behaviour with your threads at a guess but there's just no information here to work with

Comment: I understand the report is a bit light. UBsan has not seen anything, threadsanitizer and adressSanitizer also. Just one thing. With correct ulimit, RSP is around 0x7fffe47b46f0 when I print registers in the callback. It is 0x2aaabdaf86f0 when unlimited.

Comment: In gdb, go to frame 2, look at the source `network.c:149` to see how `printf` is being called, and have gdb print the arguments.

Comment: Sure.   fprintf(stderr, "Method %s\n", method);
(gdb) p method
$1 = 0x2aaac0000a80 "GET" . Also fails if I just put fprintf(stderr, "HELLO"). Whatever function call I put there segfaults. Really looks like stack corruption

Comment: It could be you're seeing a stack overflow in a thread; the 0x2xxxxxxxxxxx addresses start to appear in the thread_main_handle_connect function. Are you creating the threads yourself? How big are the thread stacks?

Comment: Question has been edited with a small example that triggers the unwanted behavior. It can now be re-opened.

Comment: From the pthread_create man page: "On  Linux/x86-32,  the default stack size for a new thread is 2 megabytes.  Under the NPTL threading implementation, if the RLIMIT_STACK soft resource limit  at  the  time  the  program  started  has  any  value other than "unlimited", then it determines the default stack size of new threads.   Using  pthread_attr_setstacksize(3),  the  stack  size attribute can be explicitly set in the attr argument used to create a thread, in order to obtain a stack size other than the default." So with `ulimit -s unlimited`, you're getting just a 2MB stack size

Comment: (I can convert that to an answer if the question gets reopened.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I also saw that looking at __pthread_initialize_minimal_internal() in libc NPTL.The manpage needs to be updated : it is also true on Linux/x86-64 . So asking for ulimit -s unlimited actually gives you a small stack size for threads ! Thank you again for investigating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Mark Plotnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554472/mark-plotnick) explained, the problem comes from the default stack size for thread. Having **ulimit -s unlimited** gives you a stack size of **2MB**, a small size by today's standards.

Looking more closely into pthread code, in **__pthread_initialize_minimal_internal()**

```
 /* Determine the default allowed stack size.  This is the size used
     in case the user does not specify one.  */
  struct rlimit limit;
  if (__getrlimit (RLIMIT_STACK, &limit) != 0
      || limit.rlim_cur == RLIM_INFINITY)
    /* The system limit is not usable.  Use an architecture-specific
       default.  */
    limit.rlim_cur = ARCH_STACK_DEFAULT_SIZE;
  else if (limit.rlim_cur < PTHREAD_STACK_MIN)
    /* The system limit is unusably small.
       Use the minimal size acceptable.  */
    limit.rlim_cur = PTHREAD_STACK_MIN;

  /* Make sure it meets the minimum size that allocate_stack
     (allocatestack.c) will demand, which depends on the page size.  */
  const uintptr_t pagesz = GLRO(dl_pagesize);
  const size_t minstack = pagesz + __static_tls_size + MINIMAL_REST_STACK;
  if (limit.rlim_cur < minstack)
    limit.rlim_cur = minstack;

  /* Round the resource limit up to page size.  */
  limit.rlim_cur = ALIGN_UP (limit.rlim_cur, pagesz);
  lll_lock (__default_pthread_attr_lock, LLL_PRIVATE);
  __default_pthread_attr.stacksize = limit.rlim_cur;
  __default_pthread_attr.guardsize = GLRO (dl_pagesize);
  lll_unlock (__default_pthread_attr_lock, LLL_PRIVATE);
```

The man-page of pthread_create(3) only mentions the default stack size for Linux/x86-32, but here are the values for other architectures in glibc 2.3.3 and up (**ARCH_STACK_DEFAULT_SIZE**):

- Sparc-32 : 2MB
- Sparc-64 : 4MB
- PowerPC : 4MB
- S/390 : 2MB
- IA-64 : 32MB
- i386 : 2MB
- x86_64 : 2MB

I have submitted a patch to the man-page to include this information. Thank you again for your help in investigating this issue.